# upstart service giving 'chdir: command not found' error

Tags: service, upstart

I've created an upstart conf script called watch_folder.conf that i have used successfully on a few ubuntu installs already but for some reason I'm getting an error from the following code:

```
#/etc/init/watch_folder.conf

description "watch folder service"
author      "Jonathan Topf"

start on startup

stop on shutdown

respawn
respawn limit 99 5


script
        chdir /home/jon/Dropbox/Render\ Farm\ 1/appleseed/bin
        exec /usr/bin/python ./watchfolder.py  ../../data/
        echo "watch_folder started"
end script
```

if I look inside /var/log/upstart/watch_folder.log i see the following

```
/proc/self/fd/9: line 2: chdir: command not found
/proc/self/fd/9: line 2: chdir: command not found
/proc/self/fd/9: line 2: chdir: command not found
/proc/self/fd/9: line 2: chdir: command not found
/proc/self/fd/9: line 2: chdir: command not found
/proc/self/fd/9: line 2: chdir: command not found
...
```

Does anybody know what may cause this error, its perplexing me!

Answer (score 0):

I't seems that I misunderstood the structure of upstart conf files, like `script`, `chdir` is a stanza so shouldn't appear within one.

More info here

https://askubuntu.com/questions/321867/upstart-service-giving-chdir-command-not-found-error#321871